# clicking on a link with scroll wheel opens in a new tab but not when right-click + open new tab is performed

Tags: javascript, tabs, popup, href

I have a link that has an onclick event which calls this function:

```
function popUp(url){
    window.open(url, '');
}
```

the link looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(popUp('someUrl'));">I'm a link</a>
```

Clicking on the link should open a pop-up window. Opening it in a new tab should also load the page. The thing is, the page loads when the scroll wheel is clicked but when you right-click on the link and then choose to open in a new tab, the new tab is blank (about:blank).

Is there any way to make the url load when right-click + open in new tab is performed?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a js function not a link, so it'll not possible to open the page in a tab. You can modify your link as

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="Javascript:popUp('someUrl')">I'm a link</a>
```

Or the direct url as href value to achieve the goal.